# Pyspark: Return next weeks saturday

Tags: pyspark

I'm trying to return next weeks Saturday date from datatype column `rel_d`.

Normally, in python, I'd subtract number of days till next Saturday and add it to the `rel_d`

```
def next_saturday(dt):
    next_sat_dt = dt + relativedelta(days=(12-dt.weekday())) # 12 as indexing starts from 0 in python
    return next_sat_dt
```

creating a UDF in pyspark for the same seems like a bulky operation. Is there some spark operation which could do it faster?

Answer (score 0):

You could use 2 `next_day` in pyspark to reach to next week's Saturday

Note that in pyspark day starts from Sunday (0) and ends on Saturday (7).

So, if you jump to next Sunday and then jump to next Saturday, it will be equal to your requirement.

Subsequently, You can also add multiples of 7 using `F.day_add` to reach nth week of your choice

```
df = df.withColumn('next_saturday_date',F.next_day(F.next_day(F.col('rel_d'), 'Sun'), 'Sat'))
```